# Storing binary Ruby Marshalled objects in Git. Use filters to convert to text (JSON or YAML) and back?

Tags: ruby, json, git, marshalling, yaml

I want to version control binary files that contain the data to run our project. The format used by the program is Marshalled Ruby objects, there is no options to change this in the program, Windows only, and it's closed source. Lovely right?

Here is some good news though. Most of the classes are well documented and for the most part are close to just being Structs, but some have custom Marshalling methods. I also plan to build tools for diffing and merging these files, but figuring out how to put them in to the repo is more important.

So, would using filters to smudge binary files into text (JSON or YAML) for storage in Git and clean them back out to binary for the working directory be a wise idea or just a waste of time?

Rough implementation of both filters, dropping imports, using YAML, and untested with Git:

```
puts Marshal.load(gets).to_yaml # Smudge

puts Marshal.dump(YAML.load(gets)) # Clean
```

Edit: Thought I should note that there is deflated Ruby scripts stored in one of these files. A clean project has about 133 KB of Zlib deflated script in it, about 800 KB when inflated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are these data files for of the RPG Maker series of game building tools?

Comment: @Wave Talk about hitting the nail on the head! I plan to talk to Enterbrain about sharing the Ruby classes from RPG Maker needed to Marshal the objects in a standalone Gem, but the diff and merge tools will not be effected by what they say as the tools and the RPG Maker classes are currently unaware of each other.

Comment: It's not so surprising, I found this thread looking for solutions to the same problem: make RMXP/VX amenable to VCS.

Comment: BTW, I found a damage calculator written in Ruby that actually parses the .rxdata files by providing its own implementation of the 'internal' game classes like Table.  You can get source here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/337225/Damage_Calc.zip or see the topic post here: http://www.hbgames.org/forums/viewtopic.php?style=26&f=179&t=67456

Comment: I also hadn't realized the Scripts file was just ZLIB deflated text--thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't get too caught up in the guideline of not storing binary files in Git.

The real challenge comes, as you suggested, in diffing and merging these files. If you store them as text, you likely don't need to do anything special here. YAML and JSON are both relatively easy to diff and merge manually.

If it is convenient, store text. This will let anybody diff the files using whatever tools they already have available.

On the other hand, if you are already planning to write your own diff and merge tools (which [can be hooked into Git](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)) you shouldn't have too much trouble storing the original binary files.

Storing binary files and using your custom diff / merge tools will require users to have those tools available for diffing and merging.

Comment: Would that cover the deflated scripts well? A large amount of the program can be scripted and a fair portion is done as editable scripts for the project.

Comment: @Spice_King, I'm not sure that I understand what you're saying.

Comment: I made a small edit at the bottom to include a bit about one of the binary files containing Zlib deflated, or compressed, scripts. I forgot about it earlier when I first posted.

Comment: @Spice_King, I don't think that makes any difference. Store text if it's convenient. If not, don't worry too much about it. Your homegrown diff and merge tools will be helpful in this case. I'll update my answer accordingly, as it currently doesn't recommend text storage first.